# If a parent has one and only child, will he not be able to learn to play the flute?

Tags: scripture, vedas, krishna, history, philosophy

My father said, "If mom and dad have only one child, then that child will not be able to learn to play the flute." I asked, "Who told you that ?" He said it was forbidden in Hinduism. Now, my question is- is it true that  If a parent has one and only child, will he not be able to learn to play the flute?

Comment: Well I don't see any logic in that and am sure there is nothing there in our scriptures wrt this statement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know is Hinduism there is no texts or scriptures stating that if a parent has one and only child that their child cannot play the flute. I searched through I internet and could not find any texts that relate to this. If we also pause and take a second to think about this we can see that there is no logic in this nor is this related to any Hindi Gods teachings. I hope this answers your question.